# Calling template function from inner class

Tags: c++, c++14

I have a class like this to call a function depending on the type. I try to compile it, but have error error C2059 syntax error : 'template'

```
class A
{
  call_1()
{
  B<type> b;
  b.template say(i);
}

template<class T>
    struct B
    {
        template <typename T, typename I>
        T say(I i) {
            return word;
        }
    };
    template<>
    struct B<void>
    {
        template <typename T, typename I>
        void say(I i) {
            /**/
        }
    };
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Or can I create functions for <void>/<non void> another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let's rewrite your example into something that is readable and is closer to being compilable, and we also print "1" or "2" in `say()` to know which function gets called:

```
#include <iostream>
using type = int;

class A {
    void call_1() {
        B<type> b;
        int i = 0;
        b.template say(i);
    }

    template<class T>
    struct B
    {
        template <typename T, typename I>
        T say(I i) {
            std::cout << "1\n";
            return T();
        }
    };

    template<>
    struct B<void>
    {
        template <typename T, typename I>
        void say(I i) {
            std::cout << "2\n";
        }
    };
};
```

OK, so first, you are trying to specialize `B` inside of `A`. This is not allowed, so let't move it outside of `A`:

```
using type = int;

class A {
    void call_1() {
        B<type> b;
        int i = 0;
        b.template say(i);
    }

    template<class T>
    struct B
    {
        template <typename T, typename I>
        T say(I i) {
            std::cout << "1\n";
            return T();
        }
    };
};

template<>
struct A::B<void>
{
    template <typename T, typename I>
    void say(I i) {
        std::cout << "2\n";
    }
};
```

Next up, you are using the same template parameter (`T`) in both `B` and `say()`. You don't need to repeat `T`, so let's delete it:

```
using type = int;

class A {
    void call_1() {
        B<type> b;
        int i = 0;
        b.template say(i);
    }

    template<class T>
    struct B
    {
        template <typename I>
        T say(I i) {
            std::cout << "1\n";
            return T();
        }
    };
};

template<>
struct A::B<void>
{
    template <typename I>
    void say(I i) {
        std::cout << "2\n";
    }
};
```

Finally, `call_1()` cannot be defined before the specialization of `A::B`, so we need to move it outside too:

```
using type = int;

class A {
    void call_1();

    template<class T>
    struct B
    {
        template <typename I>
        T say(I i) {
            std::cout << "1\n";
            return T();
        }
    };
};

template<>
struct A::B<void>
{
    template <typename I>
    void say(I i) {
        std::cout << "2\n";
    }
};

void A::call_1() {
    B<type> b;
    int i = 0;
    b.template say(i);
}
```

This should now compile and do what you want. Calling `call_1()` will print `1`. If you change the `type` from `int` to `void`:

```
using type = void;
```

it will print `2`.